# webclient upload error

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

I receive the following error when I use weblcient to upload a file

System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or
write operations.

When I started the fiddler, I receive another error

403 forbidden.

I am wondering why I received two different error depending on fiddler? Also, what does the above error message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have permission to write a file to disk?

Comment: No. But what does "The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations." mean?